# Excel не видит макрос и вылетает при его запуске

Tags: excel, vba, visual-basic

В excel книге есть 2 макроса в разных модулях. Главное: при компиляции ошибок не возникает, макросы **НЕ** private. В excel при нажатии Разработчик > Макросы одного из макросов нет. Не хватает именно function (макрос в макросе). Возможно именно поэтому excel вылетает. Как лечить? До этого такое порой было, но само как-то прошло (а может не само, я так и не понял).

Код функции:

```
Function итог1(a As Integer) As String

Dim i As Integer
i = 2

While Sheets("База").Cells(i, 14).Value <> ""

   If Sheets("База").Cells(i, 14).Value = a Then
      итог1 = Sheets("База").Cells(i, 1).Value
   End If

Wend

End Function
```

Код саба который использует функцию итог1 (не закончил):

```
Sub Итог()

Dim a As Integer
a = Sheets("База").Cells(43, 2).Value

Sheets("Конец").Cells(3, 2).Value = итог1(a)



End Sub
```

Comment: Вы хотя бы код приведите, чтобы можно было что-то понять. И если я Вас правильно понял, то `function` в принципе там быть не может. В этом окне отображаются только процедуры (`sub`) и только те, которые не имеют параметров.

Comment: Всё равно не понятно, что именно у Вас не работает. Почему функция не видна в списке макросов, я ответил выше. А так еще у Вас в функции бесконечный цикл.

Comment: @ЭдуардИзмалков странно что раньше это условие в цикле не приводило к бесконечному циклу. Почему он бесконечен?

Comment: Если условие `Sheets("База").Cells(i, 14).Value <> ""` верно, то у Вас нет выхода из цикла

Comment: @ЭдуардИзмалков вот я дурак, забыл i++ делать

Answer (score 1):

Макрос - это все: и функция, и процедура :)

Параметры можно передавать и в функции (*Function*), и в процедуры (*Sub*).

> при нажатии Разработчик > Макросы одного из макросов нет

В окне не отображаются:

- функции (*Function Test () As Double*);
- процедуры, задекларированные как *Private* (*Private Sub Test ()*)
- процедуры с передаваемыми функциями (*Sub Test (i As Long, sTxt As String)*).

> Возможно именно поэтому excel вылетает

Зачем там вообще цикл?

```
With Sheets("База")
        If .Cells(i, 14).Value = a Then итог1 = .Cells(i, 1).Value
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Макрос на то и макрос, что должен запускаться без передачи каких-либо параметров.

Если я не ошибаюсь, то макросом может быть только процедура.

Comment: Я забыл поставить i = i + 1. Она там должен ячейки одного столбца проверять, для этого нужен i.